# hide or set y-values to 0

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am importing data from a .txt file and plot it, that is working.

Now I want to hide some parts of the data, i.e. I want to set all y-values for an interval x to 0 or better hide them completely, the rest of the plot shouldnt disappear.

```
    data = pd.read_csv('C:\\users\johan\Documents\Arbeit\Schwarzkoerper\Avasoft\winkel3\\'+''.join(L[k]),sep='\;',skiprows=10,decimal=",",header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data) #muss sein
x = data[0]*10**(-9)
y = data[1]
plt.plot(x, y*Teilung())
plt.axis([450*10**(-9), 1100*10**(-9), 0, 60000])
plt.show
```

To be concret: I want to hide y-values for x in [500-600*10**(-9)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following [column operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html) with boolean condition is possibly to filter only the data you need from y-values.

```
df.y[(df.x < 500 * 1e-9) | (df.x > 600 * 1e-9)]
```

Then use the new range of y-values over the original x-values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lower_bound = 500 * 1e-9
upper_bound = 600 * 1e-9

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x" : np.linspace(0,1100*1e-9,100),
    "y" : [5*np.cos(i)+i for i in range(100)]
})
#original values
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1])

hidden_df = df.y[(df.x < lower_bound) | (df.x > upper_bound)]

plt.plot(df.iloc[:len(hidden_df), 0], hidden_df)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="x", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
plt.legend(("Original", "Hidden"))

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: original_and_hidden_plots]